# 'load data' issue in winbugs (bayesian hierarchical)

Tags: hierarchical-data, bayesian, winbugs14

I have a hierarchical linear model in Winbugs. Data is a longitudinal one and is made up of three categories(red = 1, blue = 2, white = 3)

k - total observations =280

Structure of the data is as follows:

```
N[] T[] logs[] logp[] cat[] rank[]
1    1    4.2   8.9    1     1
1    2    4.2   8.1    1     2
1    3    3.5   9.2    1     1
2    1    4.1   7.5    1     2
2    2    4.5   6.5    1     2
3    1    5.1   6.6    2     4
3    2    6.2   6.8    3     7

 #N = school 
 #T = time
 #logs = log(score)
 #logp = log(average hours of inputs)
 #rank - rank of school
 #cat = section red, section blue, section white in school
```

My model is syntactically correct, but when I try to load data, I get error = 'expected square bracket at the end]'

```
model {
# N brands
# T time periods
for (k in 1:K){
for (i in 1:N) {
for (t in 1:T) {
logs[k,i,t] ~ dnorm(mu[k,i,t], tau)
mu[k,i,t] <- bcons +bprice*(logp[t] - logpricebar) 
             + brank[cat[t]]*(rank[t] - rankbar)

}
}
}
# C categories
for (c in 1:C) {
brank[c] ~ dnorm(beta, taub)}

# priors 
bcons ~ dnorm(0,1.0E-6)
bprice ~ dnorm(0,1.0E-6)
bad ~ dnorm(0,1.0E-6)
beta ~ dnorm(0,1.0E-6)
tau ~ dgamma(0.001,0.001)
taub ~dgamma(0.001,0.001)

}
```

I follow the standard process of loading data, I select N and then press 'load data' in dialogue box.

Can someone help figure me out the issue here?

Comment: You are confusing BUGS with some of your notation. For example `N` should be a single integer if it is to be used as a count indicator in a loop, but you provide `N` as vector. Further, some data you do not provide (e.g `K`,`bcons`)?

Comment: @gjabel will you know how to include time fixed effects and product fixed effects in the code above?

Comment: @gjabel thanks!. I excluded N & T from the dataframe and it works. But then how do I include time and product fixed effects in the code.

Comment: I would rewrite the model to loop over `nobs` (i.e. the number of rows in the data frame) rather than having a loop through `k`, `i` and `t`. Then use a second loop over `ncat` to define your random effects for each section. Much like in here... http://www.bias-project.org.uk/WB2011Man/BHM-2011-slides.pdf#page=24